# nouislider rounding errors

Tags: nouislider

Here's my declaration in my angular 2 project:

```
<nouislider  [connect]="true" [min]="2.79433548546" [max]="18.5525702846" [(ngModel)]="selectedRange" [tooltips]="[true, true]" ></nouislider>
```

Initially `selectedRange`is correctly set to `[2.79433548546, 18.5525702846]`. However, as soon as I move the lower bound slider, numbers are rounded off so `selectedRange` becomes `[2.79, 18.55]`. `18.5525702846` is clearly not in this range so it is excluded from the sliding criteria. Any ideas of to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting to [two decimals is the default](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/#section-formatting). You can pass another formatter (using `[format]="formatter"` or `[config]="config"` in your declaration).

`formatter` or `config.format` would look like this:

```
format: {
    to: String,
    from: Number
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. You'd think rtfm would've helped here but for some reason I had a hard time finding the `format` feature.